# Multilingual website with not relational database

Tags: java, database-design, nosql, multilingual, bigtable

Can anyone help with advice how to organize not relational database for multilingual site? Here it is some questions about this stuff but with MySQL, etc. "multilanguage" is not only static (we can do this with framework), but with dynamic content too. And actually we don't know about how many languages user wish to create content: can create "Name" for object and translate it on as many languages as he wants.

Our team use Java Spring Framework on GAE with Objectify. But I think this is not important - what tools we're using.

Or maybe nosql databases is not actually right tool for tasks like this.

p.s. sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you give an example of what an entry in your database would look like ? I know that the point of the question is to find out how to do it, but it might help to understand with a basic example.

Comment: for example entity `Event` might have fields `id`, `logoUrl`, `startDate`, `endDate`, that do not need to localize and fields like `name`, `description`, that user can translate to English, Spanish, Russian, if event is international.

Comment: And when this information will be displayed you will have to translate not only the content, but the words "name" and "description" too, right?

Comment: Yep, but this we do now with Spring internazionalization. We translate static information like field's name + dates etc. But we think now that we want let user to translate he's content to as many languages as he wants.

Comment: There's nothing here that's specific to a nonrelational database.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't understand wrong, i think this is the best way I found for Multi-lang DB (I use MySQL, but it would be the same story):

- First of all, you should avoid to store long strings on main table (such as name, description). You can store them in different tables. Your table will be faster.
- You can use translation table for all your objects (such as product, order, shipping, etc.)

### Translation table:

```
translation_id    obj_id     lang_code    field        translation
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1              2          EN        name      Million Dollar Baby
      2              2          TR        name      Milyonluk Bebek
```

obj_id references product_id actually and can be related with product_id. I prefer obj_id, because it's easy for me to control all translation tables without remembering order_id, product_id etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, this is one way to achieve this. But this is "RDB-way". But key-value storage is different. We can do this in Google BigTable (for example) too but may be exist better choice